# Fit picture to user form layout

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I'm having a hard time tring to fit the picture into the userform background when I change the layout.

The picture just minimized and not filling the userform.

Comment: Try deleting it and then reinsert it after you make your changes

Comment: sorry it didnwt help it happens again. when I changing the layout of the form the picture in background geting smaller and smaller.